# How can i get video upload limit in facebook

Tags: ios4, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the video upload limit in facebook and i want to use it in an iphone app.

please tell me how to do it either from graph api or from legecy rest api?

Thanks

Comment: Get video limit? eh? Please rephrase the question with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Each user is subject to limits on the length and size of the video files they can upload, just like they are when uploading through Facebook. Use video.getUploadLimits to determine a specific user's limits. To increase video upload limits, users can ''verify'' their accounts with Facebook. One simple way to verify an account is by confirming a mobile phone number with Facebook. You can determine whether a user has verified their account querying for verified on the user FQL table or by calling users.isVerified, but in general you should determine a user's video limits independently with video.getUploadLimits. You might want to display these limits to the user before that user tries to upload a video to Facebook." 
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/video.upload/

That is for the rest API.

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this using the graph API? Thanks.